# RxJava single background thread scheduler

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm fairly new to RxJava so this is probably a dumb question. I am going to describe my scenario.

I have some code running on the UI thread which will update some images but those images are not very important and they consume a bit of resources while generating them so I want to generate them on a single thread (not the UI thread of course) and generate them one by one. I'm guessing the trampoline scheduler is what I want but my problem is that if I use it then it does the work on the UI thread and I want it to do it on another thread.

Obviously I can write my own thread in which I can queue items and then it processes those one by one but I thought maybe RxJava would have a simple solution for me?

My current code looks like this:

```
Observable<Bitmap> getImage = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Bitmap>() {
    @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Bitmap> subscriber) {
        Log.w(TAG,"On ui thread? "+ UIUtils.isRunningOnUIThread());
        subscriber.onNext(doComplexTaskToGetImage());
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
});

getImage.subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline()).subscribe(new Action1<Bitmap>() {
    @Override public void call(Bitmap bitmap) {
        codeToSetTheBitmap(bitmap);
    }
});
```

My log that says "On ui thread?" always has true. So how do I make that code and all subsequent attempts to do the same thing run on a single thread (not the ui thread) in order without writing a bunch of code to queue that work?

Edit:

I believe that this can now be accomplished using `Schedulers.single()` or if you want your own you can use `new SingleScheduler()`. I'm still testing but I think it does what I wanted back when I posted this.

Comment: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid

Comment: I'm already using RxAndroid and my code shows that I am using `subscribeOn`. I just don't know what to pass to `subscribeOn` to do what I want.

Comment: You need to subscribe on a background thread `Scheduler` (the [`Schedulers` class](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/schedulers/Schedulers.html) contains static factory methods for creating them). Then you need to observe on a main thread `Scheduler`, which can be acquires in RxAndroid via the `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` method.

Comment: I get that but which `Scheduler` will give me a background thread that will keep on getting reused working just like the `trampoline` scheduler?

Comment: You could create a `ThreadPoolExecuter` with a pool size of 1 (`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`), then use it to generate the schedulers via the `Schedulers.from()` method. Alternatively, you could create a custom `Thread` with a `Looper` running (e.g. `HandlerThread`), and pass a `Handler` running on that `Looper` to the `AndroidSchedulers.handlerThread()` method to get a `Scheduler` that will operate on that thread.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, I'll give those a try.

Comment: `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` seems to be doing exactly what I wanted. Thank you. If you want to put it into an answer I'll gladly mark it as answered.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create a single reusable thread to create a `Scheduler` for the `Observable` in one of the following ways:

- Create a `ThreadPoolExecuter` with a pool size of 1 (`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` is a convenient static factory method for doing that), then use it to generate the schedulers via the `Schedulers.from()` method.
- [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) provides a custom `Scheduler` implementation that uses a `Handler` to schedule the actions, and thus can be used with any `Thread` that has a `Looper` running by passing it's `Handler` to the `AndroidSchedulers.handlerThread()` factory method.

Note that you will need to observe on a main thread `Scheduler` if you're interacting with the UI at the conclusion of these tasks.

Comment: I miss a `Schedulers.singleThread()` method in rxjava, just like its `newThread()` one.

Comment: @AlvaroGutierrezPerez RxJava 2 has a new `Schedulers.single()`.

Answer (score 16):

In RxJava 2 you can use `Schedulers.single()` which:

> Returns a default, shared, single-thread-backed Scheduler instance for
>   work requiring strongly-sequential execution on the same background
>   thread.

Please [see the documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#single()) for more details.

I don't see it available in RxJava 1 [Schedulers documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/rx/schedulers/Schedulers.html).

Comment: But isnt single() returning always the same scheduler? So if you have 2 different items using single() they will both share the same thread, would they? So this doesnt answer the question since the thread wouldnt be dedicated to a job

Comment: @FrankMonza of course `single()` always returns the same thread since you want the work to be sequentially (that's the whole point of it). If you want two independent single-threaded schedulers then use [`Schedulers.from(Executor executor)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#from-java.util.concurrent.Executor-), as explained on the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `trampoline` scheduler, so it means your source observable will be run on the current thread (here is main thread).

And the `subscribeOn` will work for both upstream and downstream. That why your log shows your are running on the `main thread`

To fix this, you can use `Schedulers.single()` in the `subscribeOn`, and then `observeOn` the main thread.